# Not getting type error when not assigning the type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this code in my index.ts which is the entry point file for webpack and ts-loader

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("screen-canvas");
```

I have assigned

```
 "noImplicitAny": true
```

in tsconfig.json

this is my webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
      },
      {
        test: /\.wgsl$/,
        use: "ts-shader-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    hot: true,
  },
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },
};
```

I am surprised that i do not see any error when I have not assigned any type to canvas element in an index.ts

this is my devDependencies in package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.2.3",
    "@webgpu/types": "^0.1.32",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.4",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-shader-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "webpack": "^5.83.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  }
```

can anyone help me, please !!

Comment: I think it is because `getElementById` returns `HTMLElement | null`

Comment: there is no error even in let x = 10;

Comment: Why should there be an error? `x` is a number

Comment: when i have no noImplicitAny assigned true it mean i should always give type, right?

Comment: No. It means that you have to supply a type when the compiler cannot infer a type more specific than `any`. Type inference is your friend

Comment: so i don't need to put type everywhere and write code like js code unless i see error ?

Comment: For instance something like this: `const a = (param) => {}`

Comment: I get error of - parameter 'param' implicitly has an 'any' type but still i am not able to decide why here but not in canvas !! So how do i decide where to give type and where not?

Comment: in the case of `param` it is an argument, which has no assignment to it, so the compiler can't infer the type for you.

Comment: If you would try this instead: `const a = (param = 1) => {};` you will not get an error, since the compiler can tell that param is `number`

Comment: @wonderflame and it already knows the return type is `void` in that case as well

Comment: Basically, you won't need to assign a type in assignments, or at least I can't think of a case where you would have to.

Comment: If someone wants to answer this they should link to [the TS Handbook documentation for type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#types-by-inference).

Comment: Thank you all for this knowledge !! I always used to put type in the ts code thinking that I always need to make it a static type and can make it by giving its type. This is a new piece of knowledge that we don't need to put type inference on all things!! Thank you so much :(